# How to make an application to make the phone work after specific period of time

Tags: android

How to make an application to make the phone work after specific period of time
Example:
Child lock application this application start after answering some questions and closed after a period of time, if you didn't answer the questions the application restart automatically

Comment: It would be very kind if you write; which platform? which language? What did you do before asking? any work you did before posting.when asking questions please specify more data what you are doing. If we come to an answer:
Restarting application if it does not answer etc this is not a good idea. You may need to use a countdown timer to wait for X seconds and if no answer you may do something else. child application start another application is like a virus behaviour and does not sound good. best wises

Answer (score 0):

You can use service or job scheduler to start an application
You can also implement FCM to send push to app to wake up

Check here how to create JobScheduler
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

if you have any other doubts, mention in comments